# how to play a sound on mobile game in adobe air?

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

I am making a game in actionscript 3.0, I am able to hear the different sound of game on simulator but can't hear anything on my android/iOS device.

The code I am using is :-

```
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

private function playBgSound():void
{

    private var bgsnd:Sound = new Sound();
        bgsnd.load(new URLRequest("sound/bg.mp3"));
        //bgsnd.play();
        bgsnd.play(0, 9999);
    }
```

can anyone point what I need to change to get it running on mobile devices.

Thanks
Saurabh

Comment: On your device where is sound file placed. I think sound file is not found. Try to catch `IO_ERROR`.

Comment: ohh yes, thanks a lot, it did the trick my sound files were in a folder which wasn't present on mobile.